# CSRF token mismatch after redirecting to callback URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project running on my localhost. my payment panel wants to redirect back to my localhost verify route but I get 419 expired error.

Comment: Check the `SameSite` attribute of your session cookie.

Comment: Is there a way you can append CSRF token in the URL somewhere and do some handling on it? Looking at your question, I am assuming you are putting callback URL in the third party payment panel somewhere to redirect back to your project after the payment is done.

Comment: @CBroe its null

Comment: You cannot use CSRF protection on callback URLs, the token will never match.  (the request is coming from another client and cannot have the session token) Disable CSRF protection for that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
      // your url
    ];
}
```